# Where does Gnome Color Manager store the ICM or ICC files?

Tags: 12.04, color-management

I am trying to create a  professional photography workflow in Ubuntu. I've calibrated my monitor with a Spyder 3 (works out of the box in 12.04).

But I need to know the file path to the monitor calibration profile that is created in the Gnome Color Manager ("Color" in System Settings).

Where is the *.icm file located? It's not in the usr/share/color directory.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find your colour profiles as ICC files in ~/.local/share/icc. (Where ~ is your home folder).

The files have slightly cryptic names, but you can open them (with the ICC Profile Installer) to see a little more information. Otherwise, open the Color settings panel and click the View details button with a profile selected. The "Filename" field in that dialog should point you in the right direction.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you.

I found the file name from the 'View Details' option, but it still didn't show up when I did a search with Nautilus. Now to perfect my color managed workflow :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to search for it in nautilus.

Click [HERE](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/ProductRoot.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=120) (if the manufacturer is HP/COMPAQ-otherwise go to your monitors' website), Look up your monitor in the search bar at the top, once you get some results click on the little blue link titled "Drivers & Software". You should have results within the first 2-3 items in the search results. Look for the one that says "Software" at the far right side, click and download the "you're_file.exe".

Run it, go to the directory where it extracted its content and then just copy all or just the profile you want to the "Color" settings directory, should be `/home/YOUR_NAME/.local/share/icc` (be sure to enable hidden folders from the "View" menu at the top). Finally open up "Color", add profile and in the window that opens you'll see all the profiles you placed in the directory. Hope that helps. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Hugo's answer is related, but readers may be unaware of the difference between a downloaded ICC profile and a custom one.

It's becoming more common for manufacturers to generate *stock* ICC profiles from **average data** taken from an **unspecified number of pre- or early production test monitors** at **an unspecified time in the distant past** (distant in color accuracy terms is more that a month). These profiles are useful for someone who doesn't have a colorimeter or, better, a spectrophotometer. (So, better than nothing.)

The poster has a *custom* ICC profile **generated by a colorimeter** from **his specific monitor** at a **given point in time**. This is much better: (i) it takes into account manufacturing variances and (ii) it takes into account the changes that take place in the monitor over time.

Comment: Agreeable, but I would like to point out that it comes at the price of finding (!) and purchasing an Ubuntu- and more specifically, Argyll-compatible colorimeter, that usually costs over a hundred $ _at a minimum_, plus one has to cope with the arcanely documented Argyll software somehow, since Gnome Color Manager mentioned in the question is not supported and is not available any more.

Comment: As you can see from [this answer of mine](https://askubuntu.com/a/1319928/1157519), even built-in, generic color profiles can make a **huge** service to users, as they can facilitate essential ergonomic corrections of systems.

Comment: To be more accurate, what I meant is that a graphical "wizard" kind of a feature (like the one available in Windows, allowing for "color calibration" just by "eyeing it", without a colorimeter) is not available any more in Ubuntu (let it be part of whatever (maybe otherwise still existing) package). The feature used to exist, but as far as I could find out, like many other things in the Gnome ecosystem, got discontinued.