# Change temperature values of Night Light

Tags: display, colors, redshift

The screen of my laptop (Dell XPS 15) is rather blue. I found that I can tweak it a little bit with redshift. During the day, 6000K is the perfect temperature, in the evening I tend to use 5500K.

Ubuntu has the Night Light option, so I was wondering if I just can reconfigure the day and night colors to be the ones I now manually set with redshift. Because redshift does not persist the settings. Even after just closing my laptop, those settings are gone.

So how can I configure Night Light for both day and evening temperatures?

**UPDATE**

As [described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914500/how-to-adjust-the-hue-intensity-of-gnome-night-light), it's possible to configure the NIGHT color using the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-temperature <temperature>
```

But is it also possible to configure the DAY color as well?

Comment: Why not just read the documentation - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Redshift - specifically the `temp-day=5800 temp-night=4800` params (*changing the example values to your wanted values*)

Comment: That's a start indeed, thanks. Unfortunately, redshift seems to ignore the config file. And I'd prefer to configure the system's Night Light settings rather than install redshift manually to be able to control it.

Comment: I would expect redshift (or really any program) to read the params when it starts and not every time it gets a timeslot (which wastes resources); thus any changes you make won't be recognized until you restart it (or force it to reload the params).  Did you do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to adjust the hue (intensity) of gnome night light?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914500/how-to-adjust-the-hue-intensity-of-gnome-night-light) Also this may come in handy: https://askubuntu.com/a/967721/480481.

Comment: @guiverc Yes, I logged out and logged in again tot test the settings every time I changed something. But after logging in, everything was reverted back to the defaults.

Comment: @pomsky I found that one as well but the accepted answer only mentions how to set the night value, which is way too yellow anyway. But I would like to modify both DAY and NIGHT colors.

Comment: @wout Here's a tip, set night light to always on, then set up a cron job to change the temperature (following the linked question) periodically between DAY and NIGHT.

Comment: @pomsky THat's a good one indeed. Thanks! A good hack until I find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

> The screen of my laptop (Dell XPS 15) is rather blue.

An alternative could be to set the preinstalled `D50` color profile to the laptop screen on the standard *Settings* app's *Color* sidebar item. (Monitor calibration misery is not needed; the `D50` profile is available from the *Add profile* dialog).

[image: color profile settings UI screenshot]

This in itself compensates the blue-ness of the LCD to a really decent level.

It is not timed or periodic, it's on all the time. This could be your "day-time" compensation.

The night-light, when it gets turned on, will add its shift on top of this; they play nicely together.