# Redshift alternatives on Xubuntu 21.04 with Wayland

Tags: xubuntu, wayland, 21.04, redshift

On Xubuntu 21.04 with Wayland, Redshift doesn't work anymore.

I have already tried the following apps that were mentioned to me:

- f.lux doesn't work.
- Safe Eyes no temperature color settings.
- Blue Shift doesn't exist.
- Brightness Controller does many other things.
- Iris  doesn't exist.
- Clight doesn't exist.
- Calise doesn't exist.
- RedshiftGUI doesn't work.

Can you suggest some alternatives that work?

Comment: No alternatives needed for something that is already integrated in system settings.

Comment: sorry but I am on Xubuntu (XFCE) 21.04. Where is the tool you mentioned?

Comment: Is XFCE even compatible with Wayland? It is planned for 4.18 https://wiki.xfce.org/releng/wayland_roadmap

Comment: and then Redshift doesn't work anymore? on 20.10 it works fine

Comment: i've tried your apps but whitout success: see my first post

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1342076/does-xubuntu-21-04-use-wayland-by-default  Xubuntu 21.04 apparently does default to Wayland.  Most of those apps require XOrg, which can be run.

Comment: The easiest alternative to switch back to X.Org. Wayland does not seem to have a protocol to change screen contrast and color temperature. https://askubuntu.com/q/1286458/124466

Comment: Considering how many laptops are out there with blue-ish LCD this sounds like a very serious concern. On Gnome 3 Ubuntu 20.04 (on Xorg) one of my go-to mitigation steps is to [use the D50 preinstalled color profile in the color settings](https://askubuntu.com/a/1319928/1157519) (which I further combine with Gnome 3's night light feature). Do you find any similar color profile settings and a similar reddish-toned preinstalled color profile (like D50) on Xubuntu (21.04)?

Comment: no, XFCE cannot change the color profile. Just realized that I have X11 on my system (Xubuntu 21.04) so why all the tools aboved not work anymore?

Comment: I just clean installed Xubuntu 21.04.  Redshift installed without an issue and runs just fine.  Sometimes when you upgrade from another distro it can cause applications to not work properly.  Also, there is no sign of Wayland being installed in my Xubuntu 21.04 here.

Answer (score 0):

Tint-all has a Sephia setting - it leaves the mouse still in black and white which can probably be adjusted somehow

https://github.com/amarovita/tint-all