# Does Xubuntu 21.04 use Wayland by default?

Tags: xubuntu, wayland, 21.04

I came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341837/redshift-alternatives-on-new-xubuntu-21-04), and it seems that OP is having issues with Redshift due to Xubuntu using Wayland. I was under the impression that XFCE [plans to](https://wiki.xfce.org/releng/wayland_roadmap) support Wayland in the upcoming version 4.18, and it does not support Wayland yet.

So, does Xubuntu 21.04 use Wayland by default?

Comment: I searched in DuckDuckGo about it, but could not find anything. It would be more convenient to know it from someone who already knows the answer, than to download Xubuntu 21.04 and run it with a live USB

Comment: I just setup a VM and installed Xubuntu 21.04 to verify this and now I can honestly say, no, it does not default to Wayland.  Only x11 was installed.  I am thinking that when you perform the upgrade install to the next version that it is carrying over what may have been installed before.  Also, in that other question I did add a comment there, and I think that they need to perform a clean install.  I did a clean install and redshift installed and worked without a problem in Xubuntu 21.04.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks for the information. Feel free to modify the existing answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, it does

...as I found out after upgrading from 20.10. There were some glitches in Gnome extensions, and at one moment I noticed an error message like "this function doesn't work in Wayland".

So I rebooted and checked the login page. Indeed, the cog wheel gave me an option with Xorg and one with Wayland.

Comment: Well, there goes my usage of Xubuntu after 20.04.  Not a fan of Wayland.  :(  At least they are leaving in X.Org, so I guess that is good...

Comment: It's just a default. You can ignore it and run on Xorg.

Comment: Yeah, it will just be an irritation that it defaults to it...  Oh well, it is what it is. :)  +1

Comment: I find it weird though that the [official release notes](https://wiki.xubuntu.org/releases/21.04/release-notes) for 21.04 do not mention anything about the change in the default session. Neither had Sean Davis (the Xubuntu lead) mentioned anything in his [21.04 progress update](https://bluesabre.org/2021/02/25/xubuntu-21-04-progress-update/).

Comment: @Jos are you really running Xubuntu? (XFCE) because you mention Gnome extentions

Comment: archisman-panigrahi this answer shouldn't be marked as accepted by you. It mentions Gnome extensions so the person doesn't seem to be running Xubuntu. And @Terrance test seems to show Wayland isn't the default. (caveat it's in a VM)

Answer (score 5):

It is documented that Xubuntu (Xfce4) will be receiving Wayland in the future, but it is not there in Xubuntu 21.04 by default.  I setup a quick VM and installed Xubuntu 21.04 just to verify.  It defaults to x11 and Wayland is not a login option.

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's a VM so maybe the driver isn't marked for using Wayland by default (IIRC there is something about the driver, to have Wayland by default). So it's not representative unfortunately.

Comment: @tuxayo If it's any consolation, I cannot enable Wayland on my system regardless of VM or not.  I guess it may be possible since I use a Legacy BIOS that Wayland may not work with it.  I don't know....